# Insert after Select (Java sql)

Tags: java, mysql

Struggling with some java / sql code that carries out a stored procedure call, followed by a select followed by an insert into –

The call to the stored procedure works and creates the ‘duration’ table –

```
while(true) {

  boolean var1 = false;
  Connection var2 = DBConnPool.getInstance().getConnection();
  Statement var3 = null;
  ResultSet var4 = null;

try {
     var3 = var2.createStatement();
     String var5;
     var5 = "CALL totalduration('%', NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE, NOW());";
     var3.executeQuery(var5);
```

The select statement then runs and correctly outputs multiple rows –

```
var5 = "SELECT duration.name, zone, duration, asset.id as assetid, node.id as nodeid\n" +
        "FROM duration\n" +
        "inner join asset\n" +
        "on asset.name = duration.name\n" +
        "inner join node\n" +
        "on node.zonename = duration.zone\n" +
        "where Duration > '00:10:00'\n" +
        "and Zone = 'Reception'\n" +
        "group by duration.name DESC";
        var4 = var3.executeQuery(var5);
```

I then want to insert into a table data from the resulting ResultSet, if I use the following then it inserts only 1 row

```
 If (var4.next()) 
             {
                int var6 = var4.getInt("assetid");
                int var7 = var4.getInt("nodeid");
                String var8;
                var8 = "insert into alerts (ts, assetid, alerttypeid, nodeid, ack) values (now(), " + var6 + ", " + 11 + ", " + var7 + ", 0)";
                var3.executeUpdate(var8);
         }
```

So, I assumed the following would apply the insert to all the ResultSet rows –

```
while(var4.next()) 
         {
            int var6 = var4.getInt("assetid");
            int var7 = var4.getInt("nodeid");
            String var8;
var8 = "insert into alerts (ts, assetid, alerttypeid, nodeid, ack) values (now(), " + var6 + ", " + 11 + ", " + var7 + ", 0)";
            var3.executeUpdate(var8);
         }
```

But the error  ‘Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed’ implies that var4 is closed?

I am obviously doing something silly and perhaps the insert into should be before the select so would appreciate some guidance on the ‘correct way’ to solve this.

Regards
Active

Comment: Always use **`PreparedStatement`** when you have parameters. [**Take a look**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: Why though does the insert occur only once and not for every row? The insert probably needs to be before the select but I am not sure of the correct syntax.

Comment: FYI : you should names your variables something more usefull than `var#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaDoc from ResultSet :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, **re-executed**, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

You are using `Statement var3` to execute the update query in your loop. Since this is the same `Statement` used to recover `ResultSet var4`, that instance will be close on the next `execute#`. This is why you are able to read the first line, execute the update and then the error occus.

You need to use a different `Statement` instance to keep the `ResultSet` open. Indeed, a `ResultSet` is bind to the `Statement`.

Note :

1. `var#` are not good names for variable, `stmt`, `rs`, ... are some names that fit more and are easy to understand what each instance are without searching the declaration.
2. Note that you should also close the `Statement`, `ResultSet`, ... when you are done with them (even in case of exception). Here, I will add in the following sample a `try-with-resource`
3. Use PreparedStament instead of concatenate `String`, this will be more readable and in case of `String` value, this will be safer (against SQL-Injection)

Sample (with some improvement from the notes) :

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into a(b, c) values (?, ?)") ) {
    while(var4.next()) {
        ps.setInt(1, rs.getInt("b"));
        ps.setInt(2, rs.getInt("c"));
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
} catch( SQLException e){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks AxelH, though I get try-with-resources not supported in source 1.6 (using JDK1.6), is there an equivalent command for 1.6?

Comment: @active you have to do it yourself in the `finally` clause, checking in order if the instance is null or close it (with try-catch) for each (ResultSet, Statement, Connection). The connection should be release to the pool in your case.

Comment: Thanks AxelH, could you provide an example finally clause (I am a newbie)

Comment: Thanks, I will try and get my head around that though I may have to get some external help on this one. It seems overly complex (to me)

Comment: @active What is ? A `PreparedStatement` is a specific `Statement` that you can parametrize, you set the query once and set the parameter on the fly to execute the query. If you need more help on this, I suggest you take a look to some tutorial on JDBC.